Python - pivot / groupby - pandas long to wide
I have multiple tables that all have the same columns. the documents contain items with 3 different IDs ID1 ID2 and ID3. IDs are mostly different accros tables but there are some duplicates and there are also cases where not all 3 IDs are known. I combines the different tables and now my data looks like this (simple example):
df_A = pd.DataFrame({'ID1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', np.nan, np.nan],
                     'ID2': ['AB', 'AB', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,np.nan],
                    'ID3': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan, 'EFG','HIJ'],
                   'Source': ['source_1', 'source_2', 'source_1', 'source_2', 'source_3', 'source_3'],
                   'Count': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]})

>>> df_A

   ID1  ID2  ID3    Source  Count
0    A   AB  NaN  source_1      1
1    A   AB  NaN  source_2      1
2    B  NaN  NaN  source_1      1
3    B  NaN  NaN  source_2      1
4  NaN  NaN  EFG  source_3      1
5  NaN  NaN  HIJ  source_3      1

What I want is to transform from long to wide, with the Source as columns, so that it will look like this:
   ID1  ID2  ID3  source_1  source_2  source_3
0    A   AB  NaN         1         1         0
1    B  NaN  NaN         1         1         0
2  NaN  NaN  EFG         0         0         1
3  NaN  NaN  HIJ         0         0         1

It must be something with pivot_table and maybe also groupby. I have tried things like this:
df_A_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df_A, index=['ID1','ID2', 'ID3'],
                      columns='Source',
                      values='Count').reset_index()

But I get empty rows or errors like:
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 225. ID1 for an array with shape (30262231164,) and data type object

